# Can I decreases the size of skb_frag_t on 32-bit machines

Tags: linux-kernel

When I upgrade the linux kernel from 4.9.299 to 5.15.77, I find the size of skb_shared_info is increased from 192 to 256 and is not compatible with my WiFi driver. My machines is 32-bit and I want to decrease the size of skb_frag_t.Changes are as follows：

```
diff --git a/include/linux/skbuff.h b/include/linux/skbuff.h
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
index 1a7f2be73..8ef35ebfd
--- a/include/linux/skbuff.h
+++ b/include/linux/skbuff.h
@@ -368,8 +368,18 @@ extern int sysctl_max_skb_frags;
  */
 #define GSO_BY_FRAGS   0xFFFF

-typedef struct bio_vec skb_frag_t;
+typedef struct skb_frag_struct skb_frag_t;

+struct skb_frag_struct {
+       struct page     *bv_page;
+#if (BITS_PER_LONG > 32) || (PAGE_SIZE >= 65536)
+       __u32    bv_len;
+       __u32    bv_offset;
+#else
+       __u16    bv_len;
+       __u16    bv_offset;
+#endif
+};
```

Is there a problem with this change？Thank you!

I wonder if this change will cause other problems